# Why does socat fail at proxying X11 where ssh succeeds?

Tags: x11, proxy, socket, unix-sockets

I am investigating how to write a simple X11 unix-socket-based proxy.  I have tried various standard applications, as well as written my own code, but I am getting wildly variable results.  What's going wrong?

*Background:* My eventual goal is to implement a filtering X11 proxy for security purposes, as a lightweight alternative to xpra and xephyr.  See [Sandboxing the Firefox Browser with Firejail](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/User:Sakaki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide/Sandboxing_the_Firefox_Browser_with_Firejail#Demonstrating_the_X11_Vulnerability) for more information on X11 vulnerabilities.

#### Attempts

- `ssh localhost -X`

  We know and love `ssh`'s X forwarding. It works fine.
- `ssh localhost -R /tmp/.X11-unix/Xnnn:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`

  `ssh` can also forward sockets and X forwarding works fine over them. (N.B. You have to manually set `DISPLAY=:nnn`.)
- `socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.X11-unix/Xnnn,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`

  `socat` is a program essentially designed to be a socket proxy.  However forwarding X11 over it is flaky.  (N.B. You have to manually set `DISPLAY=:nnn`.)
- `socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.X11-unix/Xnnn UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`

  Instead of asking `socat` to fork on each connection, it can handle just one connection and then terminate.  This allows Firefox to work, but not Okular nor keepassx, and is not practical in any case, because I need a proxy that keeps running
- [A Haskell application I wrote to forward sockets](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/ad/blob/0cd0106b763b2bafc04718337868625e4b70ce50/socket/app/Main.hs)

  This application launches a thread for every incoming connection and just forwards data from the proxy socket to the server socket, and vice versa.  The results are the same as `socat fork`
- [A Haskell application I wrote to forward sockets, but only accept one connection](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/ad/blob/7af96bd47c82afc3553c038d78836342b5b4a3a4/socket/app/Main.hs)

  The same as above except it only accepts one connection.  The results are the same as `socat` no `fork`, which is suspicious.

#### Results

I tested each proxy attempt with basic X apps (`xterm`, `xeyes`, `xclock`, `xev`), Firefox, [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) and `keepassx`.  The results are as below, ✓ when it works, blank when it doesn't.  For the combinations that don't work the application just "hangs" with no output nor any sign that it's doing anything at all.

|  | `ssh -X` | `ssh -R` | `socat fork` | `socat` no `fork` | Haskell app | Haskell app, only one accept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Basic X | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| Firefox | ✓ | ✓ |  | ✓ |  | ✓ |
| Okular | ✓ | ✓ |  |  |  |  |
| keepassx | ✓ | ✓ |  |  |  |  |

#### Questions

The biggest question is why does `socat` not work whereas `ssh` does? `socat`'s only job is to forward sockets, so I am surprised that it performs less well than `ssh`, which has additional jobs besides.  I found [the source of openssh's socket forwarding](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6b977f8080a32c5b3cbb9edb634b9d5789fb79be/channels.h) but it is too complicated for me to understand why it works in a way that `socat` doesn't.

Are there obvious things that I should be writing in a socket proxy application that I might have missed?

Is there a example source code of a simple (few hundred lines) socket proxy that successfully forwards X that I can learn from?  openssh is too big a code base.

Why do `socat` and my application suddenly start working with Firefox when they stop accepting new connections?

Answer (score 4):

One or more X extensions (I think DRI is one of them) send file descriptors over the unix domain socket and using `send`/`recv` doesn't proxy these file descriptors. Instead you have to use `sendmsg`/`recvmsg` and send across all of the CMsg data.

This explains the results you found reasonably well. I don't think `socat` proxies file descriptors (there are no calls to `sendmsg` in its code) and the haskell app doesn't either. I don't understand why `ssh -R` works.

I was stumped by this issue myself when I tried to write a local X11 proxy. I ultimately figured it out by messing with the source of `xtrace` which does successfully proxy unix connections.

Comment: Oh wow, with `send/recvmsg` [it](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/ad/blob/e213b633ac05b97cf9321b3f0e0051ed12b961c3/socket/app/Main.hs#L82-L89) works! Thanks so much for this answer. I wondered if I would ever get to the bottom of this mystery.